# Use Windows function GetProductInfo via MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, api, windows, mapbasic

I develop a MapInfo-based GIS and I need to be able to determine the Windows OS of a given user. So far we have used a Windows function `GetVersionEx` (`kernel32` library) to do this but the [function doesn't behave properly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) from Windows 8.1 onwards...unless you do *Application Manifesting* which I'd rather not mess around with unless absolutely necessary.

As an alternative I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246562/how-to-get-the-os-version-in-win8-1-as-getversion-getversionex-are-deprecated) suggesting to use `GetProductInfo` instead but I don't know how to set this up in MapBasic.

The `GetVersionEx` function is first defined like this:

```
Type OSVERSIONINFO
    dwOSVersionInfoSize As integer
    dwMajorVersion As integer
    dwMinorVersion As integer
    dwBuildNumber As integer
    dwPlatformId As integer
    szCSDVersion As String * 128
End Type

Declare Function GetVersionEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetVersionExA"
    (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As integer
```

(OSVersionInfo documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx))

And then called in MapBasic:

```
Dim OSInfo as OSVersionInfo
Dim nRet,iMaj_Version As Integer

'Set the structure size
OSInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = 148    'Len(OSInfo)

'Get the Windows version
iRet = GetVersionEx(OSInfo)

'get values e.g.:
iMaj_Version = OSInfo.dwMajorVersion
```

so it will be similar to this I expect...but I don't know how the new function needs to be defined or how I then get the output in to a MapBasic variable.

Finally, we are using the 32-bit version of MapInfo so for the time being I'm not interested in potential help/solutions for the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully implemented [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/73000/getting-operating-system-version-info-even-for-win) solution.

[image]

Based on that I have created .NET assembly (*.dll).

After that all you need is to declare the method in your MapBasic application:

```
Declare Method OSName
    Class "nmiDotNet.MBOSinfo" 
    Lib "nmiDotNet.dll" () As String
```

And you can call this method like simple function in MapBasic:  `OSName()`

I customized output string to get names like this:

```
Windows 10 Professional Bit64 
Windows 8 Professional Bit64 
Windows 7 Enterprise Bit64 (Service Pack 1)
Windows 7 Enterprise Bit32 (Service Pack 1)
Windows XP Professional Bit32 (Service Pack 3)
```